# Keeping app in iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios7

I have clients who wish to not upgrade there applications to *iOS 7*, however I have downloaded *xCode 5.0*.

I need to make amendments to the application.

Is there a way that I am able to keep the app like the *iOS 6* version?

When I research this I get irrelevant results about not being able to downgrade and features of *iOS7*.

Thank you.

Comment: What is not clear: do you like to have tha app look as an iOS 6 app on an iOS 7 device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An iOS 6 app (using only the api available in iOS 6) build against the iOS 7 SDK does run on iOS 5 and iOS 6 (and on those OSes it should look as if it had been build against the iOS 6 SDK). You have to set the deployment target and check in Simulator using iOS 6/5 simulators if everything is running.

However, I found that some UI components had slight position changes - so you should check the app.

Update: As mentioned by borrrden: if you like to have the iOS 6 look and feel on a device running iOS 7, you have to build with iOS 6 SDK.

Comment: Be aware that iOS7 only feature won't run on iOS5/6 device

Comment: If the deployment target is iOS 6, I assume that he cannot or at least does not use iOS 7 only feature. However, good hint, since I am not sure if XCode is given a warning in all cases when analysing the code.

Comment: Thanks guys, so so long as my deployment target is iOS 6 it will only deploy the app in ios 6? but still run on ios 7?

Comment: Yes, but you won't have the new iOS7 look for native component

Comment: You *will* have the new look if you build against iOS 7.0 SDK and run on iOS 7.0.  The deployment target doesn't matter for that.  It only specifies which versions your app **can** run on.  The only way to avoid the new UI altogether to build against a lower SDK and the easiest way to do that is to use Xcode 4.6.  Otherwise, iOS 6.x and 5.x will continue to run as normal if you are not worried about your client running on iOS 7.0.